# How can I force my web page to force a cell phone browser to be viewed in landscape mode?

Tags: css

In my real code, I am making a series of animations that in order to look better it is necessary for the user to hold their cell phone `horizontally`. when I click on a button I activate a `fullscreen` mode and in this mode I want all my content to go into `landscape` mode

Something like when you see a video on YouTube, if you activate fullscreen mode the video is put in horizontal mode and you as a user see that it would look better if you turn your cell phone in horizontal mode, I want the user to be forced to flip it

I want to do something like in this gif, by default this is the vertical mode, but in any moment,I need it to somehow display horizontally on the cell phone.

[image]

I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to lock viewport to Portrait Orientation in HTML5/CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359782/how-to-lock-viewport-to-portrait-orientation-in-html5-css3)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this by triggering a class change or an animation? The site where I found it made a good point that some people may have their phones screen locked and that this wouldn't be good UX. They recommended going with a message in portrait mode "This content can only be displayed in landscape orientation".

```
#container { display:block; }

@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){

  #container {

    height: 100vw;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);

    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);

    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);

    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);

    transform: rotate(90deg);

  }

}

@media only screen and (orientation:landscape){

  #container {

     -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);

     -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);

     -o-transform: rotate(0deg);

     -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);

     transform: rotate(0deg);

  }

}
```